# how to access fields in mongo document

Tags: php, mongodb, codeigniter

I have a php codeigniter web app that has a mongo db backend. 
i'm stuck for now using the mongoclient library for php.

I often have to run commands like this:

```
   $result = $collection->find(
                                array("didnum" => $didnum)
                                );
   $result = iterator_to_array($result);
```

Assuming that $result looks like this:

```
array (size=1)
  '5824b9376b6347a422aae017' => 
    array (size=10)
      '_id' => 
        object(MongoId)[22]
          public '$id' => string '5824b9376b6347a422aae017' (length=24)
      'users' => 
        array (size=1)
          0 => 
            array (size=2)
              ...
      'rules' => 
        array (size=1)
          0 => 
            array (size=5)
              ...
      'id' => string '5824b9376b6347a422aae017' (length=24)
      'last_assigned' => string 'missing' (length=7)          
      'widgetnum' => string '+18455100023' (length=12)          
      'location' => string 'missing' (length=7)
```

What is the easiest way to access the location field? 
In other words, in cases where I know there will only be one result, I'm still finding that i have to loop through $result because the array is an associative one, and i won't know what the ID is.

Just wondering if there's an easier way to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not very much into PHP, but `findOne` method [seems to exist for PHP binding](http://php.net/manual/en/mongocollection.findone.php) as well as other languages' bindings

You can use `$collection->findOne` instead of `$collection->find`